# $L(U,W)$ as a subspace of $L(U,V)$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Let $U,V$ be $\mathbb{K}$ vector spaces and $W$ a subspace of $V$.

Let $L(U,V)$ be the set of linear functions from $U$ to $V$.

We want to show that $\frac{L(U,V)}{L(U,W)} \cong L(U, \frac{V}{W})$.

This was an exercise for my Linear Algebra class. The solution included the argument that $L(U,W)$ is a subspace of $L(U,V)$ is. This seems problematic to me, since the functions have different codomains.

My solution included showing that it is isomorphic to a subspace of $L(U,V)$.

Is this what we call an abuse of notation? How come it is correct to view it a subspace, if the objects differ?

Comment: Yes, functions from $U$ to $W$ are 'treated' as functions from $U$ to $V$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/201510/305862